# Regarding passing a variable in Body Data

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter

I am trying to make a rest call to elastic search and in the window called "HTTP Request", under the body data tab, I am putting my post data as:

I am usin the bool query to get some data by passing a variable, and not a hard coded id.

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"_id": "${someId}"}}]}}}
```

When I execute this, in the results tab, I am getting the following:

Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to contain /${someId}/

It looks like the JMeter is treating the variable someId as a text. I want it to treat it as a variable. Can someone please let me know how to change the sytext in body data so that JMeter reads my variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined a variable it is possible to use it in requests, assertions, etc.

Remember the following nuances:

1. Variables scope is limited to current thread group only.
2. Variable names are case sensitive. I.e. `myvar` and `Myvar` are completely different variables
3. Variables can be set:

   - in [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) element
   - using [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) config element
   - in the runtime (as a result of Regex evaluation etc.)
4. Variables can be converted to Properties which have "global" scope and can be [shared across different thread groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups).